# NullInjectorError: No provider for Auth

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, ionic-framework, inject

I have a problema with this service.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WriUZ.png)

This is my app.module.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRCX6.png)

The injection in InicioPage:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXOuy.png)

I tried , add in providers in iniciopage.module, but not work

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding these two lines in app.module.ts

```
import { FIREBASE_OPTIONS } from "@angular/fire/compat";
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    { provide: FIREBASE_OPTIONS, useValue: environment.firebase}
  ]
})
```